# Скрипт для получения информации для Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Есть проект, управление версиями идет через Git. Используем метки `tag`, чтобы выставлять версионность проекта. Сейчас переходим на автоматическую сборку проекта через *Jenkins*. Хотим автоматически получать информацию от *git* (в частности использовать команду `git describe`) и парсить ее.
Сам с git-ом работаю недавно и не знаю как написать bat-файл, чтобы получить нужную информацию из git-a и передать её в Jenkins.

Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, и как ее решили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставите [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy%20plugin) и [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) на Jenkins. А в job-е в *Pre Steps* делаете следующее:

1. Добавляете шаг *"Выполнить команду Windows"/"Выполнить команду shell"*, которая вычитает нужные данные из вывода `git describe` и создаст текстовый файл, например, `env.txt` в формате `KEY=value`. Пример готового файла:

   ```
   MY_TAG=sometag
   ```
2. Добавляете шаг *"Inject environment variables"* и указываете упомянутый выше файл в качестве *"Properties File Path"*.

   Теперь все ключи из файла станут доступными на любом этапе сборки переменными окружения. Например, `$MY_TAG`.
3. Обработайте данные, как вам нужно, в groovy скрипте:

   ```
   def myTag = build.properties.get("envVars")['MY_TAG']
   // делаем магию с myTag
   ```
4. Если нужно из groovy-скрипта породить новые переменные окружения:

   ```
   def paramsAction = new ParametersAction([
       new StringParameterValue("SOME_VAR", result), 
       new StringParameterValue("SOME_OTHER_VAR", someValue1)
   ])
   build.addAction(pa)
   ```

Comment: Идея такая, чтобы как то передать в переменную данные из `git describe` и затем выполнить внешнюю задачу, в которую и передать параметр. Внешняя задача, правит файл проекта, внося туда информацию о программе, в том числе и номер билда. Как запустить задачу с параметром знаю. А вот в какой строке выполнить запрос к `git` и присвоить переменной никак не соображу ((

Answer (score -1):

У jenkins есть плагин git. Скорее всего он позволит решить ваши проблемы

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?